# Connecting a USB hub to itself

Tags: usb

What happens if one connects a USB hub to itself?  That is, were I to get a USB A-to-B cable and connect the A and B ports on a hub, what would occur?  I’m hesitant to simply try it out, as I know the analogous procedure for older Ethernet hubs can cause some fairly pathological behavior.

Comment: Try it! Worse case scenarios: You get 127 devices that don't do anything, or B you have to reboot to regain control of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

On most hubs nothing would happen if the hub is not switched on or plugged in. Are you saying that another power supply is connected besides the mini usb? If so it may or may not (depending on the design) cause short circuiting.

Comment: Yes, this is an externally-powered hub.

Comment: Then it may cause short circuit depending on hub.

Comment: Ideally the hub should not even activate the downstream ports since it cannot connect to a host.